# How to pass context down to the Enzyme mount method to test component which includes Material UI component?

Tags: material-ui, enzyme

I am trying to use `mount` from Enzyme to test my component in which a several Material UI component are nested. I get this error when running the test:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'prepareStyles' of undefined

After some digging, [I did found that a theme needs to be passed down in a context](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/4021). I am doing that in the test but still get this error.

My test:

```jsx
import expect from  'expect';
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import {mount} from 'enzyme';
import SearchBar from './SearchBar';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';

function setup() {
  const muiTheme = getMuiTheme();

  const props = {
    closeSearchBar: () => {},
    fetchSearchData: () => {},
    data: [],
    searching: false
  };

  return mount(<SearchBar {...props} />, {context: {muiTheme}});
}

describe('SearchBar Component', ()=> {

  it('Renders search toolbar properly', () => {
    const wrapper = setup();
    expect(wrapper.find('.toolbar').length).toBe(1);
    expect(wrapper.find('button').length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

My searchbar component is a stateless component, so I am not pulling in any context. But even when I am, I still get the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try adding `childContextTypes` in the `mount` options:

```jsx
return mount(
  <SearchBar {...props} />, {
    context: {muiTheme},
    childContextTypes: {muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object}
  }
);
```

By doing it you set the Enzyme wrapper to make the `muiTheme` available to it's children through the context.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what it was missing. 
I guess I'm gonna have to look up the React context a little bit more as was trying to pass `contextTypes: {muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object}`, but not `childContextTypes`.
Thanks Nicolas!

Comment: same works with `shallow`, just replace mount by shallow.

Comment: Thanks a ton for this! I can't believe it was that simple. I was already accepting that I would need to always wrap my tested components in the redux store provider.

Comment: shallow works for only one level, that's the point of it.  Jordan Harband from enzyme pointed this. You can check this [issue](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/664) and this [issue](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/770) on github.

Answer (score 2):

this is my handy method to test Material UI with shallow and mount

```js
...
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider'
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';

const muiTheme = getMuiTheme();
const shallowWithContext = (node) => shallow(node, {context: {muiTheme}, childContextTypes: {muiTheme: PropTypes.object}});

const mountWithContext = (node) => mount(
  node, {context: {muiTheme}, childContextTypes: {muiTheme: PropTypes.object}}
);


// now you can do
const wrapper = shallowWithContext(<Login auth={auth} onChange={() => 'test'} />);
```