# confused about Enzyme mount() context options

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I am trying to test a React component with Mocha/Enzyme which relies on a child component and one of it's child components as part of the test. I get an error related to this. My question (for now) isn't about the error but about the "context" options of mount().

I can't find anywhere where these options are explained in any reasonable detail. I don't know what values they are supposed to take and how they relate to my components. Is there a tutorial somewhere, a blog post or something which explains these options for mount() in detail?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass context down to the Enzyme mount method to test component which includes Material UI component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38264715/how-to-pass-context-down-to-the-enzyme-mount-method-to-test-component-which-incl)

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/mount.md Is this what you need to perform?

Comment: Unfortunately no but at this point I'm not sure the error I was getting is actually related to that. Still that documentation is pretty sparse and doesn't explain the concept very well at all.

Comment: Documentation is weird